# Can I trust Java SecurityManager sandbox?

Tags: java, security, applet, sandbox, securitymanager

I'm writing a JavaFX2 application that accepts arbitrary code to be loaded from remote locations. For me using a custom SecurityManager, ClassLoader and ProtectionDomain was the way to go. Unfortunately this seems to be the same setup that's used to sandbox applets, which has caused a lot of security exploits and that in turn has persuaded people to fear Java Web Plugin and removing it from their OS entirely.

Is Java sandbox a secure environment to run untrusted code onto, or is it just the Java Web Plugin as a whole to be insecure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The security manager provides your app. with exactly as much protection as it provided the plug-in.  Which was, given the security bugs, 'not much'.

It currently plugs the known security bugs (AFAIU).  But as in any complex plug-in there are probably more, yet to be discovered, or possibly to be introduced in new versions or new APIs.

So basically, your code should go somewhat beyond a standard security manager, black-listing entire packages and (if need be) providing utility methods through which to perform activity normally handled by that package.

But then, that advice is the first point of a 20+ point list that I might be able to name 2 or 3 of the possible things an app. might need to guard against, in running untrusted code.  Though that is not the question..

> Is Java sandbox a secure environment to run untrusted code onto..

No.  Java security might provide a good starting point for security against untrusted code, but it would need to be expanded specific to the app., and have other elements in order to be suited to the task required.  Even then, there are the 'unknown security bugs' (in both the JRE as well as your own security efforts) to consider.